# Scala cannot access object classes

Tags: scala, object, methods

I'm obviously missing something fundamental here. I have the following Scala Code:

```
package org.carlskii

import java.io._
import java.security.cert.CertificateFactory
import java.security.Security
import org.bouncycastle.jce.provider._

object Main extends App {

  Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider)
  val provider = new BouncyCastleProvider
  val in = new FileInputStream("cert.cer")
  val certificateFactory = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X509", provider)
  val certificate = certificateFactory.generateCertificate(file)
  println(certificate.getClass)

}
```

Which produces this:

```
class org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.X509CertificateObject
```

So I have a Bouncy Castle `X509CertificateObject` object. If I call the `certificate.getPublicKey` method it correctly returns the public key for the certificate.

However if I call `certificate.getSerialNumber` it throws the following error:

```
error: value getSerialNumber is not a member of java.security.cert.Certificate
println(certificate.getSerialNumber)
```

The interesting thing here is that Scala thinks it's a `java.security.cert.Certificate` and not an `org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.X509CertificateObject` object. Why is this the case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [generateCertificate](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/security/cert/CertificateFactory.html#generateCertificate%28java.io.InputStream%29) method returns a [Certificate](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/security/cert/Certificate.html) object, if you are sure you're going to get a `org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.X509CertificateObject` just cast the result to it:

```
package org.carlskii

import java.io._
import java.security.cert.CertificateFactory
import java.security.Security
import org.bouncycastle.jce.provider._

object Main extends App {

  Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider)
  val provider = new BouncyCastleProvider
  val in = new FileInputStream("cert.cer")
  val certificateFactory = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X509", provider)
  val certificate = certificateFactory.generateCertificate(file).asInstanceOf[X509CertificateObject]
  println(certificate.getClass)

}
```

Comment: Thanks very much thats sorted it and you've saved me from pulling my hair out.

Answer (score 1):

Method generateCertificate return type Certificate, so val certificate is inferred to have type certificate.
Method generateCertificate has a method signiture of:

```
Certificate generateCertificate(InputStream inStream)
```

When you assign a result of this call to a val scala compiler will infer the type of certificate, and that is type Certificate that method generateCertificate is returning.

So if you want to call methods that are defined on a type of X509CertificateObject you have to first cast it to a correct type:

```
certificate.asInstanceOf[X509CertificateObject]
```

What you get from getClass is a runtime class of an object.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean here. Please could you elaborate? Obviously I'm missing something obvious here!